# Constructor cannot be instantiated

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following simple code:

```
package week_4

object Pattern_matching {
  trait Expr
  case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr {}
  case class Sum(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr {}

  def eval: Int = this match {
    case Number(n) => n
    case Sum(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
  }
}
```

The errors I get are in lines 9 and 10. What do I not understand in terms of data types?

(error message is: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found   : week_4.Pattern_matching.Sum  required: week_4.Pattern_matching.type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `this`. It can only be type `Pattern_matching` so it can't be either of the case classes. And the `Expr` trait doesn't have an `eval` member.

I'm going to guess you want something like this.

```
object Pattern_matching {
  trait Expr {
    def eval: Int = this match {
      case Number(n) => n
      case Sum(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
    }
  }

  case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr
  case class Sum(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
}
```

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you for your prompt and helpful response!